# Force Index disadvantages

Tags: mysql

I am using FORCE INDEX. Eventually i can able to use the desired column as KEY..

But i just wanted to know what are the disadvantages of FORCE INDEX

Answer (score 2):

You can read this [article](http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/):

> Does this mean that we should always use a Force Index hint?
>
> NO! Using FORCE INDEX() indiscriminately can also easily backfire. The
>   distribution of the data or the values of query parameters can change,
>   and the key that you thought was best for the query can, over time,
>   become a less preferred plan. FORCE KEY should be used when you
>   understand exactly why you are using it, and are 100% sure that there
>   is no way the key that is being forced could become bad.
>
> Note, that most often the need for FORCE KEY arises when the query is
>   not very straightforward and there is no “awesome” winner key that the
>   optimizer can easily spot. Such needs can often be addressed by
>   re-writing the query and/or adding better keys.